# This code is not thread-safe, isn't it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, thread-safety, errno

I saw a piece of code like this and wondered whether this is thread-safe:

```
int savedErrno = errno;

//call some function that may modifies errno

if (errno == xxx)
   foo();

errno = savedErrno;
```

I don't think this is thread-safe, am I correct?

But I saw people write code like this, so I am not sure...

Can any one help me clarify this, thanks...

Comment: Where do you see the unsafe part kai ?

Comment: @littleadv the reason it doesn't look thread-safe is because it looks like errno is a global variable and therefore shared by all threads.  I think that was originally case, until clever system implementers "fixed it" by replacing the global variable with some macro-magic to make errno a per-thread-local variable.  It's still an ugly mechanism though IMO...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each thread has its own (thread specific) copy of errno so that looks like it should be safe.

From man (3) errno:

> errno is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type int, and must not be explicitly declared; errno may be a macro.  errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread does not affect its value in any other thread.

Answer (score 1):

The code is only using errno in one thread, in fact the code only shows one thread.
So, this snippet is thread safe.